# Make a custom listview

Tags: android

I'm going to make a custom `ListView` with icon and label of applications installed on Android device I made some code but I don't know why when I run the application my `ListView` is empty here is the codes :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ArrayList<String> AppLabel = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Drawable> AppIcon = new ArrayList<Drawable>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final ListView MyListView = (android.widget.ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    EditText MyEditText = (android.widget.EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    CustomAdapter Adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,
    MyEditText, AppLabel);
    MyListView.setAdapter(Adapter);




   PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
   List<ApplicationInfo> apps = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);

    for(ApplicationInfo app : apps) {

    String Label = (String)pm.getApplicationLabel(app);
    AppLabel.add(Label);


    Drawable Icon = pm.getApplicationIcon(app);     
    AppIcon.add(Icon);
       }//End for

    Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}//end onCreate


class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<string>{
public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource,
            EditText myEditText, ArrayList<String> appLabel) {
        super(context, resource);
        }
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    if (row==null) {
        LayoutInflater Inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        row = Inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false);    
    }//End if
    EditText MyEditText = (android.widget.EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    MyEditText.setText(AppLabel.get(position));
    ImageView MyImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    MyImageView.setImageDrawable(AppIcon.get(position));
    return (row);
    }//End get view
  }//End CustomAdapter Class

 }//end Main Class
```

Comment: why do you extend an arrayadapter to use only half the functionnalities ?

Answer (score 0):

Add getCount() to your custom adapter with the size of your arraylist.

Comment: the ArrayAdapter should take care of this. This issue is rather that the adapter is not given the array at any time

Answer (score 0):

Take reference from the view converView

```
EditText MyEditText = (android.widget.EditText)converView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
MyEditText.setText(AppLabel.get(position));
ImageView MyImageView = (ImageView)converView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
MyImageView.setImageDrawable(AppIcon.get(position));
```

Answer (score 0):

go here

http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429

Comment: More details than just posting a link to a tutorial are very helpful, especially for future users of the site.